# Установка зависимостей из registry

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Есть ли способ указать alias для registry при использовании `pip`? Иными словами, я хочу сделать так:

```
pip install -r requirements --registry my-custom-resgistry
```

Где и как в таком случае объявить `my-custom-resgistry`? Хотелось бы, чтобы эти записи лежали в `~/.pip/pip.conf` или аналогичном конфиге.

Мне важно сделать именно alias, покуда команда `pip install -r requirements --registry my-custom-resgistry` будет лежать прямо в репозитории и следовательно, будет доступна всем желающим. Мне же требуется скрыть credentials.

Возможно, есть способ указать путь к конфигу при установке.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Сделать alias судя по всему невозможно. Но есть возможность указать путь до `PIP_CONFIG_FILE=/path/to/pip.conf`

Таким образом, проблема решается несколькими конфигами.